# iPhone, Three20 Library (Is The Library Being Maintained?)

Tags: iphone, three20

Is the Three20 library (http://three20.info) being maintained?

There are a number of outstanding bugs reported on GitHub. I'm not sure if any are being actively worked.

The last check-in was over 9 months ago (relative to November, 2012).

I understand there is no support for Retina.

Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No development is going on.

There are some merges from time to time to development branch, but mostly build-fixes, no features and bigger changes.

Comment: Even the original author of that library has been recommending that people stop using it.

Comment: Thanks guys. Marcus - citation please. I'm making the case to yank Three20 from our product. I could not find such a citation last week.

Comment: Even without a citation, you might want to drop it. As I'm the last guy merging and seeing the pull requests, I'd say it's time to move on ;)

Comment: @Stephan. Thanks. Before you step out, could you increase warnings and then ensure a clean compile (its a security gate for us). Here's the list that will uncover some problems with Three20 (less -Wconversion): -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-overflow -Wformat=2 -Wformat-security -Woverloaded-virtual -Wreorder -Wsign-promo -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wstrict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-pragmas

Comment: @noloader Sure, just let me know the pull-request.